# boto3 s3 connection error: An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListBuckets operation

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using the `boto3` package to connect from outside an s3 cluster (i.e. the script is currently not being run within the AWS 'cloud', but from my MBP connecting to the relevant cluster). My code:

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['aws_access_key_id'],
    aws_secret_access_key=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['aws_secret_access_key'],
)

bucket = s3.Bucket(self.settings['S3']['bucket_test'])

for bucket_in_all in boto3.resource('s3').buckets.all():
    if bucket_in_all.name == self.settings['S3']['bucket_test']:
        print ("Bucket {} verified".format(self.settings['S3']['bucket_test']))
```

Now I'm receiving this error message:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListBuckets operation
```

I'm aware of the sequence of how the aws credentials are checked, and tried different permutations of my environment variables and `~/.aws/credentials`, and know that the credentials as per my .py script should override, however I'm still seeing this SignatureDoesNotMatch error message. Any ideas where I may be going wrong? I've also tried:

```
  # Create a session
    session = boto3.session.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['aws_access_key_id'],
        aws_secret_access_key=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['aws_secret_access_key'],
        aws_session_token=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['session_token'],
        region_name=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['region_name']
    )

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

...however I also see the same error traceback.

Comment: The issue happens when the provided credentials are wrong.Can you verify it by configuring a aws cli and running aws s3 ls s3://mybucket.You can also pass --debug option to debug the issue.If the credentials are wrong try re-generating keys in IAM and use them in your script.That should solve the issue.

Comment: @bdcloud: thanks, progress...I just ran from Terminal "aws s3 ls 'my-bucket'" and the contents i.e. files of my bucket were shown. So that seems fine. I understand there is: 1) A REST- and HTTP-Query access key for the AWS Service API (the one I was provide recently);
2) An SSH Key for CodeCommit; 3) A Git-HTTPS Keys. How can I ensure the correct one is used in my script?

Comment: In general, if you are running code from an EC2 instance, you should assign a Role. If you are running on your own computer, then store the credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`. Your code should never need to reference the credentials themselves. For example, it should just use `s3 = boto3.resource("s3")` without specifying anything more.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this was partly answered by @John Rotenstein and @bdcloud nevertheless I need to be more specific...

The following code in my case was not necessary and causing the error message:

```
  # Create a session
    session = boto3.session.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['aws_access_key_id'],
        aws_secret_access_key=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['aws_secret_access_key'],
        aws_session_token=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['session_token'],
        region_name=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['region_name']
    )
```

The credentials now stored in `self.settings` mirror the `~/.aws/credentials`. Weirdly (and like last week where the reverse happened), I now have access. It could be that a simple reboot of my laptop meant that my new credentials (since I updated these again yesterday) in `~/.aws/credentials` were then 'accepted'.